# Is there a free way to compress a PDF?

Tags: software-rec, pdf, compression

I have several PDFs that are quite large (one is 80+ MB). Is there a free way to compress that PDF to a smaller size?

Comment: Is there a way to do it from a command line in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also [Free PDF Compressor](http://download.cnet.com/Free-PDF-Compressor/3000-2250_4-10420962.html). It gives you the option of using the Flate or RunLength compression algorithms as well as different compression levels.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't support PDF 1.6 or higher.

Comment: Being made a year after the freeware version of PDF compress, I think it's safe to say it will support newer PDFs than the freeware PDF compress at least. I've had no problems with it.

Comment: For a PDF from a scanned image, I only got 1.5% compression

Answer (score 5):

I guess, the most voluminous parts in your document are the images. How much you could shrink the size then, depends if and how the images are currently compressed.

You can use ghostscript to compress all (especially bitmap) images in your PDF. 
If you will tolerate a lossy compression, you can simply use the following command (AFAIK JPEG is the default compression):

```
ps2pdf input.pdf compressed.pdf
```

And yes, `ps2pdf` can (despite of its name) also read in PDF files. Of course, there are tons of options for ghostscript, so for details please refer to the [documentation](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm).

Here is a comparison between different methods for an *example* document. (The result will vary very much depending on the contents of the input document, so always recheck the different methods for your situation.)

```
input.pdf             24 707 180 bytes
output_flate.pdf      23 293 759 bytes   # lossless via Free PDF Compressor 1.12
output_runlength.pdf  23 293 759 bytes   # lossless via Free PDF Compressor 1.12
output_jpeg.pdf       12 503 901 bytes   # lossy via ghostscript
```

You see, the lossless compression does not gain much im my case, as all images are already flate compressed in `input.pdf`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried compressing your file with the ["smallpdf" online pdf compressor?](http://smallpdf.com) 
My record is to get 92% compression. :)

Comment: Really great tool. Should be getting more traffic.

Comment: Great. **1.** I can download to SmallPDF service my 354.59 Mb PDF document. / **2.** [**354.59 → 48.38**](https://i.imgur.com/UQWIsdR.png). / **3.** [**Uncompressed**](https://i.imgur.com/5WYHyvd.png) — [**compressed**](https://i.imgur.com/cMKOAdj.png). No difference. / **4.** I can do it **free**. / **5.** And quick. Thanks.

Comment: this is no longer free

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the actual size of PDF files by compressing text and graphics with **[PDF Compress](http://www.filetransit.com/view.php?id=22058)**.

[image]

*Version 1 is freeware, [Version 2](http://pdf-compress.smartcode.com/info.html) is shareware.*

Answer (score 1):

PDF's can get compressed. Specially if they have a lot of images.

I usually compress my PDFs with [this online tool](http://smallpdf.com). Its very simple. But with a 80mb file you might not want to upload it and use a local tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try PrimoPDF, many people use it, it's really good.

Check it out on [www.primopdf.com](http://www.primopdf.com)

You have to print a document (to a "Primo PDF" printer) in order to see the results in Pdf!