# Compress pdf file?

Tags: pdf, compression

I need to reduce the size or compress a PDF file. The PDF file is actually scanned images. Is there any way by which I can compress the file?

Comment: Related: [Is there a free way to compress a PDF?](http://superuser.com/questions/85083/is-there-a-free-way-to-compress-a-pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://blog.nitropdf.com/index.php/2008/02/11/5-tricks-to-shrinkreduce-pdf-file-size/) to some good recommendations. Most of them require either using [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/) or NitroPDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Free PDF Compressor](http://www.shivaranjan.com/2009/04/02/how-to-compress-pdf-files-to-reduce-file-size/) a shot. It's a portable freeware.

Comment: i tried but no changes at all. Does a full version required? Thought it is "Free PDF Compressor" it ask us to buy. :(

Comment: The link on that page seems to belong to paid version. [This link](http://www.portablefreeware.com/download.php?id=494) is for the free & portable one. Hope that helps.

Comment: it is not compressiong to the expected rate. A 3.5mb file after compression becomes just 3.25MB. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use some software like: [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/) , [PDF Enhancer](http://www.apagoinc.com/prod_home.php?prod_id=37) or [PDF Compress](http://www.topshareware.com/PDF-Compress-transfer-13828.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Decent PDF compression products will segment scanned images into components and compress each according to content. This results in much smaller scanned pages which look identical to the original.

Examples include:

- Nuance Omnipage which uses MRC compression.
- Solid PDF Tools which uses CGM compression (my company's product).

Typically these kinds products will break the pages into parts that make sense from a compression point of view:

- photo-like images are downsampled (say from 300dpi to 150dpi) and then compressed with lossy compression (Jpeg or Jpeg2000)
- black text is compressed using lossless compression (CCITT Fax for example)
- "flat" color (like graphs, etc) is converted to palettized images.
- etc.